# Running python scripts remotely using API and subprocess does not work

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have python script (lets call it script1.py) which uses *execnet* module to launch other script (script2.py) remotely on other machine. Important part of it looks something like this:

```
import script2
host = "name@ip"
gw = execnet.makegateway("ssh={}".format(host))
channel = gw.remote_exec(script2)
```

It is irrelevant what is it doing, because when i launch it in terminal it works perfectly fine. Now I try to launch it through Flask API. I am using subprocess module to spawn new process with script (works perfectly fine with any other script that does not require connection to another machine). Basically it should work is like this:

sending request for launching script -> spawning subprocess with script1.py -> inside script1.py importing script2 and launching it on other machine using execnet

When I do this I get an error:

```
 ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
 Permission denied, please try again.
 ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
 Permission denied, please try again.
 ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
 Permission denied (publickey,password).
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/ubuntu/script1.py", line 23, in <module>
 gw = execnet.makegateway("ssh={}".format(host)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/execnet/multi.py",
 line 128, in makegateway gw = gateway_bootstrap.bootstrap(io, spec) 
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/execnet/gateway_bootstrap.py",
 line 98, in bootstrap bootstrap_exec(io, spec) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/execnet/gateway_bootstrap.py",
 line 50, in bootstrap_exec raise HostNotFound(io.remoteaddress) execnet.gateway_bootstrap.HostNotFound: remote@10.10.1.2
```

It is weird that I can do it in linux terminal, but not by launching it as subprocess with API. Does anyone have any idea why it is not working?

Comment: When you connect from the terminal, do you require a password?

Comment: Yes, it asks me to type password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to enter a password when you `ssh` to your remote host. While this works fine from the terminal, when you're trying to run the same command under `flask` it doesn't have any way to ask you for a password.

It's trying to use the `ssh-askpass` command, which can be used to bring up a dialog box in which you can enter the password; this is often used in GUI environments where you may be run `ssh` without a password. However, that's not really an appropriate solution for what you're doing, because ideally you don't want to have to manually interact with your code every time it needs to authenticate.

The typical solution for this issue is to use ssh key-based authentication: create a public/private keypair for use by your application, place the public key in the appropriate `authorized_keys` file on the remote host, and ensure that when your Python code spawns an ssh connection it uses the corresponding key file.

---

Incidentally, the  documentation for `execnet` says:

> execnet currently is in maintenance-only mode, mostly because it is still the backend of the pytest-xdist plugin. Do not use in new projects.

Comment: Thansk for explaining the issue